# Android - Buttons change when I scroll

Tags: java, android, button, listactivity

Im writing a country/capital flashcard app for history class. If I click the button, and it changes to the capital, when I scroll down, then scroll back up, it reverts to the state. How can I stop this from happening? here is my code:

```
package com.example.hostoryflashcards;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class EastEurope extends ListActivity {
    String capital[] = {
            "Albainia", "Belarus", "Bosina and Herzegouina", "Bulgaria",
            "Croatia", "Czech Republic", "Estonia", "Finland", "Greece",
            "Hungary", "Kosovo", "Latvia", "Lithuania", "Macedonia", "Molova",
            "Montenegro", "Poland", "Romainia", "Russia", "Serbia", "Slovakia",
            "Ukraine", "RELOAD"
    };
    String answer[] = {
            "TIRANA", "MINSKA", "SARAJERO", "SOFIA", "ZAGREB", "PRAUGE",
            "TALLINN", "HELSINKI", "ATHENS", "BUDAPEST", "PRISTINA", "RIGA",
            "VILNIUS", "SKOPJE", "CHISINAU", "PODGORICA", "WARSAW", "BUCHAREST",
            "MOSCOW", "BELGRADE", "BRATISLAVA", "LJUBLJANA", "KIEV"
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        loadActivity();
    }

    private void loadActivity() {
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(EastEurope.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, capital));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        TextView ov;
        ov = (TextView) v;

        if (ov.getText().toString() == answer[position]) {
            ov.setText(capital[position]);
        } else {
            ov.setText(answer[position]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to make a custom ArrayAdapter and overrides the getView method, which checks the state of each element, if you need more clarification please post your xml layout of the listView cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that you're changing the displayed view, but not the underlying data.  When the adapter needs to recreate the view, it uses the data which hasn't changed.

Given that, the best approach is to change the data and tell the adapter to update, rather than changing the views themselves.

Add a changeable list and use it in the adapter:

```
ArrayList<String> displayed;

// in loadActivity
displayed = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(capital));
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, displayed));
```

Then change the data when a list item's clicked and notify the adapter:

```
// In onListItemClick
if (displayed.get(position).equals(answer[position])) {
    displayed.set(position, capital[position]);
} else {
    displayed.set(position, answer[position]);
}
((ArrayAdapter) getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to android and not sure if this is the standard way of solving this, but I have solved this problem by storing the selected state of your element(s) in a field.  When you scroll, check the state of your button and if it should be selected, perform whatever actions you wish on it (Highlighting it, changing its text, clicking it, etc.)

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Could you write a sample piece of code that would do what you mentioned above? Im new to android as well and a bit confused.

Comment: My solution doesn't have anything at all to do with Android, just Java.  All you want to do is store the view and position of the selected item, and in your adapter's "getView()" method, put in a check for this view and position.  If it is the selected button, have it display the text you want.

Comment: blahdiblah 's solution is also pretty solid if you want a second point of attack.